# Bash script not handling npm commands correctly

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I have a script that runs some `git` and `npm` commands based on a user like

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/su someuser -c "
cd /opt/app1/;
env -i git remote update;
env -i git pull origin dev;
cd /opt/app1/client/;
npm run build;
"
```

The `git` commands run correctly. The `npm` command runs and builds the files but throws lots of errors about

```
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 9.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

If I run `npm run build` as the user from terminal, everything builds fine. I even tried `env -i npm run build` in the script and that just says `env: ‘npm’: No such file or directory`. So i then tried `env -i /usr/local/bin/npm run build` and oddly that returned `/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory`.

I though that the `user -c` would set me up with all env like the user was logged in and that `env -i` would give me clean `env` without the parent.

also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/su someuser - -c "
cd /opt/app1/;
git remote update;
git pull origin dev;
cd /opt/app1/client/;
npm run build;
"
```

That last attempt returns same as first: git commands work, build throws errors about sass and environment as if something is different than when i run the command as the user from the terminal.

Any idea why this command is not working correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Olorin's suggestion to look at the node error, I explored that more. Despite the fact that `node -v` for `someuser` was returning `v9.4.0` and the `locate` command not finding any `v8` versions installed for any user, and having re-installed `node`, i was still getting the same error. The following command works. Note the `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh;`

```
#!/bin/sh  
/bin/su tstapps -c "
cd /opt/app1/;
git remote update;
git pull origin dev;
cd /opt/app1/client/;
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh;
npm run build;
```

At one point I had `nvm use v9.5.0` and then tested it still works without it. Next I removed `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh;` and it was broken again. So apparently the `nvm` isn't available in `shell-scripts` `env` without sourcing it and the `npm run build` needs to see `nvm`.

Strange issue and looks like some users ran into similar issues with using `nvm` resources in `bash` based on [this thread](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/521). Still not sure where it was getting the `v8` from. Unless it was getting `v8` from the `include/node` directory of `v9` installations. Example:

```
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-platform.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-profiler.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-testing.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-util.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-value-serializer-version.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-version-string.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8-version.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8.h
/home/someuser/.nvm/versions/node/v9.5.0/include/node/v8config.h
```

Comment: Yep, `nvm` does rely on environment variables to do its work. I'd misread your comments, and thought you used `npm` somehow for this and not `nvm`.

Answer (score 1):

`env -i` cleans the environment, and that includes the `PATH` variable, which is used to look up commands if you don't give the full path. So, with `env -i`, you need to specify the full path to commands being invoked. With `npm`, what probably happens is that `npm` itself is a script which has `#! /usr/bin/env node` as the shebang, so the lookup for the `node` command fails.

If you need to clean the environment, try either of:

- `sudo -iu someuser sh -c "...."`
- `su someuser - -c "...."` (both these commands start login shells with some cleaning of the environment)
- or, with `env`, retain some environment variables, like the Ubuntu `service` command does:

  ```
  $ grep env $(command -v service) -m1
  out=$(env -i LANG="$LANG" LANGUAGE="$LANGUAGE" LC_CTYPE="$LC_CTYPE" LC_NUMERIC="$LC_NUMERIC" LC_TIME="$LC_TIME" LC_COLLATE="$LC_COLLATE" LC_MONETARY="$LC_MONETARY" LC_MESSAGES="$LC_MESSAGES" LC_PAPER="$LC_PAPER" LC_NAME="$LC_NAME" LC_ADDRESS="$LC_ADDRESS" LC_TELEPHONE="$LC_TELEPHONE" LC_MEASUREMENT="$LC_MEASUREMENT" LC_IDENTIFICATION="$LC_IDENTIFICATION" LC_ALL="$LC_ALL" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "$SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" status 2>&1)
  ```

  You probably don't need all those, but keep `$PATH`, `$TERM`, and maybe set `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: I updated my answer with the result of changes. Note that i'm using `su` vs `sudo` because i need any user that is part of the group that can run that command to be able to run it without sudo and without a password. The command worked great until we needed to `npm run build` as part of the process.

Comment: @jtlindsey I don't understand what you mean by the part where you say "because ... without a password". It's easy to setup NOPASSWD rules with `sudo`, and if you can use `su`, you can use `sudo` for that. Also, in the edit, `env` without any options is meaningless, you might as well run the commands without it. Note how the output says that it expected Node 8.x and got 9.x. How did you install/setup Node 8.x for your user?

Comment: Fixed last edit. For the install, I logged in as the user and did npm install and then confirmed all npm commands worked from command line before logging out. So i'm not sure how a v8 is showing up. Node legacy is not installed and the user node env is v9

Comment: Did you add anything to `.profile`, etc. for setting up npm?

Comment: No, i used the `nvm install` and i checked both .profile and .bashrc of the user and there is nothing explicitly pointing to any v8 of node that i can see.

Comment: Just did a locate command to see where any v8 node might be and removed all of them (nvm leave behind previous versions). Then i removed node modules, did `npm install` again to re-install modules, and same issue. `npm run build` works if i do it from terminal but it breaks in the middle of the build process when run from script. At this point i don't know where it is getting the v8 from because `locate` doesn't find v8 anywhere anymore.