# Shell script throwing /usr/bin/env: ‘node’ on npm install

Tags: shell, path, node.js

I cant seem to figure this out, although reading a lot of threads with this problem.

**Summarize the problem**

From a shell script, login in to remote server, pulling a git repo and trying to run "npm install" with absolute path to Node I get "/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory"

**Provide details and any research**

I have installed Node with NVM. When running "which node" on remote server I get the following path "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin/node". Im logging in as root with SSH-key to the remote server.

My shell script look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh root@my-ip -p my-port<<EOF
cd projectDir/my-project
git pull origin master
~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin/npm install
pm2 restart all
exit
EOF
```

When running the shell script I get the following output:

```
mesg: ttyname failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
From git+ssh://github.com/xxxx/my-project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
-bash: line 4: pm2: command not found
```

NVM-version: 0.35.3
Node-version: v12.16.2

**When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried**

I have tried with different paths to my Node-version but getting the same result.
When logged in to the remote server over SSH as user and not via the shell-script and running "~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/bin/npm install" it works like a charm.

Comment: The slanty quotes around `node` look like a problem. Make sure you use a text editor, not a word processor, when writing code.

Comment: Im using VIM when editing the shell-file.

Comment: Well, env is looking for a command named `‘node’` and it can't find it in your PATH. Try `cd project_dir; shopt -s dotglob; grep -r '‘node’' .` and see what comes up

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I needed to add "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh;" before running my npm command.

For a more elaborated answer look at this thread where I found the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425819/411880